# Simple Excel Linking

Tags: vba, excel

I have a fairly simple question that I have been unable to find an suitable answer for; I have an excel sheet with many SQL tables nested in the worksheet. I now need to add one more table, but this new table will be over 30 mb and when added to the current file, it makes the entire workbook trudge along very slowly for even simple calculations.

My question is: can I insert this table into a new excel file and then refresh it from my original file using the VBA code I already have that refreshes all my other SQL tables? If so, what would I have to add to my VBA code to refresh the new table in the new file? Let's assume the new table's name is "NewTable" and the file path would be C:\Users\davidmo\Desktop\David

Here is my current VBA Macro:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
DoEvents

ActiveSheet.Range("Q45") = Now

End Sub
```

If it helps, I am envisioning being able to open my original file, click the VBA macro button I use to refresh all my SQL tables and it would also refresh the table in the different file. Then I'd run my formulas in the original file and just reference the newly updated table from the other file.

Comment: The straightforward solution would be to open the workbook and call `.RefreshAll` on it then close it. Are you looking for a way to refresh it without opening it? I dont see how that would be possible.

Comment: Yeah the idea is to not have to open any other workbooks. The file I'm working on is a dashboard for work and so the less I have to do to refresh the dashboard, the better.

So from what you think, there's no way to somehow say "Refresh.NewTable" at file path C:\\etc

Comment: I (personally) dont know of a way to do that without opening the file.

Answer (score 0):

So this will open the woorkbook and refresh the table and then close it, if the workbook is already opened it will stay open. There is no way to do it with a closed workbook, but its not visible for the user anyway.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim FileName As String
Dim Path As String
Dim Opened As Boolean

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

Path = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Files\1.xlsx" 'Edit Path
If IsWorkBookOpen(Path) = False Then
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path)
Else
Path = Right(Path, Len(Path) - InStrRev(Path, "\"))
Set wbk = Workbooks(Path)
Opened = True
End If
wbk.RefreshAll
If Opened = False Then
wbk.Close (saveChanges = True)
End If

DoEvents
ActiveSheet.Range("Q45") = Now

End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Wow that looks really nice. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Tried this macro and the debugger errors out on the third to last line "Case Else: Error ErrNo" with an error message of "File not found".

Comment: ofc, you have to link the file where your seperated table is in. if youve done that it should work.

Comment: Sorry mate, I'm all self-taught when it comes to computers and programming so I'm afraid I have to ask what you mean by "link the file". @UGP

Comment: If i understood you correctly then the error should come from this line `Path = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Files\1.xlsx"` . You have to take the filepath of the workbook with the seperated table, you made and exchange it with that line. Directory + Filename.